# Whenever I am clicking save button in this SetupActivity my app crashes. My app is crashing whenever I am going to WRITE in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I Am creating a Login/Register Activity in my android app. When a user is registering the Firebase Authentication is working fine. After Registering a use is directed into Setup activity. Now the setup activity is to store data into Firebase Database. Whenever the user is completing setup and clicking on the button to update in the database. The app stops working.

```
private Button SaveInformation;
 SaveInformation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                SaveAccountSetupInformation();
            }
        });
```

[When the app is crashing the logcat is showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUwXo.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QluzP.jpg)

[The App is showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuVSd.jpg)

**The Code of my Setup Activity is:**

```
package com.example.application;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SetupActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText FirstName, LastName, Day, Month, Year;
    private EditText Country, State;
    private ImageView ProfilePic;
    private Button SaveInformation;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;


    String currentUserID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup2);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);


        FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_FirstName);
        LastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_LastName);

        Day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_date);
        Month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_month);
        Year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_year);

        Country = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_country);
        State = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_state);

        ProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.setup_profilePic) ;

        SaveInformation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setup_button);

        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        SaveInformation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                SaveAccountSetupInformation();
            }
        });
    }

    private void SaveAccountSetupInformation()
    {
        String firstName = FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
        String lastName = LastName.getText().toString().trim();

        String day = Day.getText().toString().trim();
        String month = Month.getText().toString().trim();
        String year = Year.getText().toString().trim();

        String country = Country.getText().toString().trim();
        String state = State.getText().toString().trim();


        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your username...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your full name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(country))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your country...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(state))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your state...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(day))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your full name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(month))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your month...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(year))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your year...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Saving Information");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating your new Account...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            HashMap userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("FirstName",firstName);
            userMap.put("LastName",lastName);

            userMap.put("day",Day);
            userMap.put("month",Month);
            userMap.put("year",Year);

            userMap.put("country",country);
            userMap.put("state",State);

            userMap.put("Status","Hey There !! I am using Toodle.");
            userMap.put("Gender","Default");
            userMap.put("Institution","Default");

            UsersRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity2.this, "your Account is created Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message =  task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity2.this, "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }


            });

    }
}

    private void SendUserToMainActivity()
    {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Error in My LOGCAT when the app crashes.**

```
2020-09-13 11:05:00.540 20182-20182/com.example.application E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.application, PID: 20182
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getText
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(CustomClassMapper.java:477)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(CustomClassMapper.java:329)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:166)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:141)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:65)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.updateChildrenInternal(DatabaseReference.java:412)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.updateChildren(DatabaseReference.java:392)
        at com.example.application.SetupActivity2.SaveAccountSetupInformation(SetupActivity2.java:141)
        at com.example.application.SetupActivity2.access$000(SetupActivity2.java:26)
        at com.example.application.SetupActivity2$1.onClick(SetupActivity2.java:72)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24811)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error as shown in logcat is

```
 Found conflicting getters for name: getText
```

the Firebase Database can only store JSON types but you send to it an Edit Text
the error exactly here

```
  userMap.put("day",Day);
        userMap.put("month",Month);
        userMap.put("year",Year);
  userMap.put("state",State);
```

you send Day ,Month ,Year and State as Edit Text not String
do it like these

```
  userMap.put("day",day);
        userMap.put("month",month);
        userMap.put("year",year);
   userMap.put("state",state);
```

and it will work fine